# Overriding default parameters in Ruby on Rails with URL query strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This sounds like it should be a simple question, but here's the route:

```
get 'routes(/:start_system/:end_system(/:result_type))' => 'routes#calculate',
    :defaults => { :start_system => 'Jita', :end_system => 'Renyn', :result_type => 'short', :min_sec => -1.0 }
```

The defaults are overridden if I give a URL in this form (for example, we can use integers for the systems instead of their names):

```
host/routes/30000001/30001437
```

However, I am trying to provide more information in format strings after, which is not working:

```
host/routes/30000001/30001437?min_sec=0.5
```

Basically, the default { :min_sec => -1.0 } is never overridden by the format string at the end of the URL. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `defaults` option is only working for params, which you explicitly specify in your route.

You could get the behaviour that you need by modifying your route like this:

```
get 'routes(/:start_system/:end_system(/:result_type)(/:min_sec))' => 'routes#calculate',
    defaults: { start_system: 'Jita', end_system: 'Renyn', result_type: 'short', min_sec: -1.0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's not 100% clear from the routing guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) but it seems you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which would maintain your design:

1. Remove default for `min_sec` from `routes.rb`.
2. Implement default in controller:

   `def calculate
     min_sec = params['min_sec'] || -1.0
     ...
   end`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm going to mark the other as the answer but only because it technically is the correct answer. This is what I am going to use.

Comment: Glad to help and thx for the vote.  FWIW I think the correct answer is the one which meets the poster's requirements but I can get by without the checkmark :).

Comment: To be fair, though, that answer encouraged me to write a bug report for the rails documentation, so it fits in my requirements and might lead to some change in the docs.